# Debug code regarding parsing a string character by character in NASM assembly for IA32

Tags: linux, debugging, assembly, x86, nasm

I am a novice in assembly programming.I stumbled across a program in which i am required to  write a code to take a string and a number from the user and increment each character of the string by the given number.

I have done the following:-

```
    section .bss
        s2 resb 20   ;output string
        s1 resb 20   ;input string
        num resb 2   ;input number
        count resb 1 ;length of the input string
    section .data

    section .text
        global _start
    _start:
        mov eax,3      ;taking input string from the user
        mov ebx,0
        mov ecx,s1
        mov edx,20
        int 0x80

        mov eax,3     ;taking input number from user
        mov ebx,0
        mov ecx,num
        mov edx,2
        int 0x80

        mov al,'1'     ;initializing count to 1
        sub al,'0'
        mov [count],al

        mov ecx,20     ;no of times the loop can execute
        mov esi,s1     ;to use movsb on s1 and s2
        mov edi,s2

        mov bl,[num]     ;converting string num to integer
        sub bl,'0'

        loop1:      ;parse the string character by character
        lodsb 
        cmp al,00   ;exit out when encounter end_of_file
        je _exit
        add al,bl
        stosb
        inc byte [count]    ;increament count for every possible character except end_of file
        loop loop1

    _exit:
        cld
        rep movsb
        mov edx,count
        mov ecx,s2
        mov ebx,1
        mov eax,4
        int 0x80

        mov eax,1
        int 0x80
```

When i run the code,it produces the expected output and some gibberish characters.
I am not able to understand the problem with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near the end:

```
    mov edx,count
```

This loads the `edx` register with the *address* of `count`, which is something like 0x804912a.  You don't want to write 0x804912a bytes.

You want `edx` loaded with the *contents* of `count`.  Note that `count` is a byte but `edx` is a 32-bit register, so you'll want to zero-extend it.  You probably want to replace that instruction with

```
    movzx edx, byte [count]
```

After the change, your program works as expected.